# SUSE_Linux zypper installing Fail

Tags: linux, curl, suse, zypper

I'm using SUSE linux server and i tried zypper command as below..

```
zypper install [argument]
```

But the result message poped up

```
Retrieving repository 'sles112repo' metadata [\]
Download (curl) error for 'http://mirror.asterdata.com/sles/11.2/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'mirror.asterdata.com'

Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a):     http://mirror.asterdata.com/sles/11.2/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Invalid answer
```

And i tried to access that above URL by command

```
curl "http://mirror.asterdata.com/sles/11.2/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml"
```

then the message comes out

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'mirror.asterdata.com'
```

I guess I need to fix that URL setting
How can i solve this problem??

Comment: Wrong site, no bearing to anything programming. Try **Super User** or **Unix & Linux**.

Comment: @tink Super User means sudo command??

Comment: No, different website. Stackoverflow is for programming questions.  http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux